# AS3 How to Set Up A Max Time Count Up

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, timeout

I have the following count up code, but am not sure how I would be able to include an if else statement to have the count-up stop at 15 seconds for example.

Here is the code:

```
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(100);
    timer.start(); 
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTickHandler);
    var timerCount:int = 0;

    function timerTickHandler(Event:TimerEvent):void{
       timerCount += 100;
       toTimeCode(timerCount);
    }

    function toTimeCode(milliseconds:int) : void {
        //create a date object using the elapsed milliseconds
        var time:Date = new Date(milliseconds);

        //define minutes/seconds/mseconds
        var minutes:String = String(time.minutes);
        var seconds:String = String(time.seconds);
        var miliseconds:String = String(Math.round(time.milliseconds)/100);

        //add zero if neccecary, for example: 2:3.5 becomes 02:03.5
        minutes = (minutes.length != 2) ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
        seconds = (seconds.length != 2) ? '0'+seconds : seconds;

        //display elapsed time on in a textfield on stage
        timer_txt.text = minutes + ":" + seconds+"." + miliseconds;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for efficiency, you can use the timers built in `currentCount` property to know how much time has elapsed (instead of making a `timerCount` var to that end)

To stop the timer after 15 seconds, simply set the appropriate repeat count so it ends at 15 seconds, or stop it in the tick handler after 15 seconds have past:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(100,150); //adding the second parameter (repeat count), will make the timer run 150 times, which at 100ms will be 15 seconds.
timer.start(); 
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTickHandler);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerFinished); //if you want to call a function when all done

function timerTickHandler(Event:TimerEvent):void{
   toTimeCode(timer.delay * timer.currentCount); //the gives you the amount of time past

   //if you weren't using the TIMER_COMPLETE listener and a repeat count of 150, you can do this:
   if(timer.delay * timer.currentCount >= 15000){
       timer.stop();
       //do something now that your timer is done
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks LDMS! There is a typo in the code though: if(timer.dealy should be: if(timer.delay ...